Assert that unittest Mock has these calls and no others
Mock.assert_has_calls asserts that the specified calls exist, but not that these were the only calls:
from unittest.mock import Mock, call

mock = Mock()

mock("foo")
mock("bar")
mock("baz")

mock.assert_has_calls([call("foo"), call("bar")])  # this passes the assertion

How can I assert that mock has only been called with foo and bar and nothing else?
I naively thought I could use a set like this, but call is not hashable:
assert set(mock.mock_calls) == {call("foo"), call("bar")}


The best approach is going to depend on the context of what you're actually testing. Maybe the number of calls is relevant. Maybe you can just assert on the set of strings with which it is acceptable for the function to have been called. Maybe you can assert that the mock calls list is equal to a list of call objects. Maybe you should use a test double that errors if called with an invalid input.

maybe list and sorted might work, something like that sorted(mock.mock_calls) == sorted([call("foo"), call("bar")])

@jonrsharpe for example, I could precede assert_has_calls with assert len(mock.mock_calls) == 2, but I'm surprised there's no out-of-the-box or "supported" ways to do it!

@user70 that's certainly what ChatGPT thinks would work, but without a key function to sorted I don't think you can be sure they'll come out in the right order.

Called exactly once with each set of args
First check the total number of calls made:
assert len(mock.mock_calls) == 2
mock.assert_has_calls([call("foo"), call("bar")], any_order=True)

This will only pass if mock has been called once with foo and once with bar.
Not called with any other set of args
If you don't mind how many times the mock has been called with foo and bar as long as it was never called with anything else then, inspired by this answer, you could use the fact that call objects pass a comparison test by doing this:
expected_calls = [call("foo"), call("bar")]
assert not [
    call for call in mock.mock_calls if call not in expected_calls
]

Called once with each set of args in specific order
Use this answer and compare lists.

Just compare lists instead of turning mock_calls into a set:
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock, call
...
... mock = Mock()
...
... mock("foo")
... mock("bar")
... mock("baz")
...
<Mock name='mock()' id='139760821226528'>
>>> mock.mock_calls == [call('foo'), call('bar')]
False
>>> mock.mock_calls == [call('foo'), call('bar'), call('baz')]
True

You can use that boolean comparison in an assert statement:
assert mock.mock_calls == [call('foo'), call('bar')]


If you don't care about call order:
assert any(
  mock.mock_calls == list(x)
  for x in itertools.permutations(
    [call('foo'), call('baz'), call('bar')], 3
  )
)


I like this answer, but it does depend on the order of the calls to foo and bar which is a downside. (Although I was vague about that in the original post just saying "has only been called with foo and bar" so I didn't make that clear)

Right, I thought you wanted to verify call order. If that's not the case, you could whip up something with any and itertools.permutations...

I've updated the answer with exactly that as an example.

Wow, that update with permutations is . I love it. It almost feels like there should be something in the library to support doing exactly this, because I wouldn't want to type that out in every project!

You could also do something a bit simpler but along these lines like this: assert not [call for call in mock_calls if call not in expected_calls].

Stick it in a utility module and call it something like only_these_calls so you can write assert only_these_calls(mock, [call('foo'), call('bar')])

I've stolen my idea out of the comments here and added it to my answer because I quite like it.
